# How to make Feedback disappear with user action in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

What do I need to add to the code, so that when the user clicks the button `New` or starts typing in the inputfield `"userAnswer"` for a second try, the Feedback disappears.
But the feedback should always appear when user clicks `check`

This is the simplified version of the code:

```js
function F1() {
  Z1 = document.getElementById("Z1");
  Z2 = document.getElementById("Z2");
  rZ1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  rZ2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  Z1.innerHTML = rZ1;
  Z2.innerHTML = rZ2;
  var operators1 = ['+', '-'];
  oper1 = document.getElementById("operator1");
  op1 = operators1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  oper1.innerHTML = op1;
  rnd = parseFloat(eval(rZ1 + op1 + rZ2));
  answer.innerHTML = rnd;
}

function F2() {
  antw = parseFloat(document.getElementById("userAnswer").value);
  
  feedBack = document.getElementById("feedBack");
  
  ant = document.getElementById("answer").textContent;
  {
    if (antw == ant) {
      feedBack.textContent = "good";
    } else {
      feedBack.textContent = "bad";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>

<label id="Z1"> </label>
<label id="operator1"> </label>
<label id="Z2"> </label>
= <input id="userAnswer" type=text>
<button onclick="F2()">check</button>

<p id="feedBack"> </p>

<p> <label id="answer"></label> </p>
```

Comment: Do you want to delete only what is in `<p id="feedback">`?

Comment: yes, as soon user clicks button [New] or starts typing in the inputfield ["userAnswer"]

Comment: but it should appear always when user clicks [check]

Comment: I added a response that erases the `feedBack` when clicked new or when writing something in`input #userAnswer`

Comment: Thx! @AksJacoves is there a way where also the users input in the field "userAnswer" gets erased when user clicks "new"

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer with this function (added at the end of `F1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a function at the end of the code to disappear with `feedBack` and a line was added in `F1` and `F2` to display and disappear with `feedBack` (I added a comment on those lines)

```js
function F1() {
  Z1 = document.getElementById("Z1");
  Z2 = document.getElementById("Z2");
  rZ1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  rZ2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  Z1.innerHTML = rZ1;
  Z2.innerHTML = rZ2;
  var operators1 = ['+', '-'];
  oper1 = document.getElementById("operator1");
  op1 = operators1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  oper1.innerHTML = op1;
  rnd = parseFloat(eval(rZ1 + op1 + rZ2));
  answer.innerHTML = rnd;
  document.querySelector('p#feedBack').style.display = 'none' // add this
  document.querySelector('#userAnswer').value = ''
}

function F2() {
  antw = parseFloat(document.getElementById("userAnswer").value);
  
  feedBack = document.getElementById("feedBack");
  
  ant = document.getElementById("answer").textContent;
  {
    if (antw == ant) {
      feedBack.textContent = "good";
    } else {
      feedBack.textContent = "bad";
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('p#feedBack').style.display = 'block' // add this
};

document.querySelector('#userAnswer').addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if(document.querySelector('p#feedBack').style.display == 'block')
    document.querySelector('p#feedBack').style.display = 'none'
})
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>

<label id="Z1"> </label>
<label id="operator1"> </label>
<label id="Z2"> </label>
= <input id="userAnswer" type="text" >
<button onclick="F2()">check</button>

<p id="feedBack"></p>

<p> <label id="answer"></label> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to the F1-function

```
document.getElementById('feedBack').classList.add('hidden');
```

and to the CSS a new entry for the hidden class to hide the element if exists.
For displaying the feedback if check is pressed remove similar in F2 this class.

```
document.getElementById('feedBack').classList.remove('hidden');
```

```js
function F1() {
  Z1 = document.getElementById("Z1");
  Z2 = document.getElementById("Z2");
  rZ1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  rZ2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  Z1.innerHTML = rZ1;
  Z2.innerHTML = rZ2;
  var operators1 = ['+', '-'];
  oper1 = document.getElementById("operator1");
  op1 = operators1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  oper1.innerHTML = op1;
  rnd = parseFloat(eval(rZ1 + op1 + rZ2));
  answer.innerHTML = rnd;
  document.getElementById('feedBack').classList.add('hidden');
  
}

function F2() {
  antw = parseFloat(document.getElementById("userAnswer").value);
  
  feedBack = document.getElementById("feedBack");
  
  ant = document.getElementById("answer").textContent;
  {
    if (antw == ant) {
      feedBack.textContent = "good";
    } else {
      feedBack.textContent = "bad";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('feedBack').classList.remove('hidden');
};
```

```css
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>

<label id="Z1"> </label>
<label id="operator1"> </label>
<label id="Z2"> </label>
= <input id="userAnswer" type=text>
<button onclick="F2()">check</button>

<p id="feedBack"> </p>

<p> <label id="answer"></label> </p>
```

Comment: the feedback should appear when user clicks check

Comment: Now it will be displayed if checked is prressed.